# IDEA not showing JavaDoc for decompiled Java class files

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I don't see the documentation in my Maven project for Java dependencies that are decompiled from .class files. It **does** work for external Maven dependencies.

I have activated the following settings.

`Settings->Importing->Automatically Download->Sources & Documentation`

And also, right click `pom.xml` and download documentation there.

How can I make IDEA fetch documentation for these core Java files?

Refer screenshots below to see examples of both scenarios.

[image: image with no documentation loaded]

[image: image with documentation loaded]

Comment: there is a link for "download sources" at the end of that yellow bar

Comment: is there actually documentation provided in those classes?

Comment: @Kartik no there isn't (I assume since these are local sources)

Comment: @Stultuske I am not sure, but I assume SimpleDateFormat would have detailed documentation. Are there 2 versions of the SDK with and without documentation included?

Comment: @john well then it should not be "decompiled".. are you sure you have configured jdk and not jre in the IntelliJ settings?

Comment: @Kartik Yes I am using JDK. This is the jar file from where this class is referenced from: https://i.imgur.com/tyKNXaa.png

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the sources are attached to the JDK configuration. It should work out of the box, but it could be that your JDK installation is incomplete and is missing the sources.

`src.zip` must be present in the **Sourcepath** of the JDK configuration:

[image: src.zip]

Try reinstalling JDK from the official download page and configure it again in IntelliJ IDEA.