# How to include javadoc into a decompiled code in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community edition and i previously used to read decompiled source code with javadoc simply by clicking CTRL + ClassName or methodName or so.

But i have messed up with some settings which i don't remember and therefore can't find it again and now decompiled classes just show me the code with no javadoc.

Please help, how do i get everything back?

For example,
System.out.println();
I'm holding Ctrl and click on the "println"
What i expect is opening decompiled PrintStream.class with description of all methods and fields, but now that description is missing and i only see the code.
I did not use any extra plugins, just the one that ide offers by default.

Comment: This has nothing to do with disassembly, right? You just want to see the javadoc description of a certain class. Point the mouse cursor to the `println()` of `System.out.println();`, and IDEA will automatically jump out of the corresponding Javadoc Instructions, and then you can click [...] to pop up `Open in Documentation Tool Window Ctrl + Q` or `Jump to Source F4`, especially `Jump to Source F4` is probably what you thought it was disassembled source code. but

Comment: I tried this but when i hover the cursor over println() it only says: java.io.PrintStream  public void println()  <1.8>. As well as when i open it in documentation tool window

Comment: My IDEA version is `IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 (Community Edition)`, My IDEA is use default config. Test Project create step: `File` -> `New` -> `Project`, Build system: `Intellij`, JDK: `temurin-1.8(Eclipse Temurin version 1.8)`.

Comment: I've just tried to do so, but the result is the same. It seems that i have somehow changed the default config for this and don't know how to change it back.

Comment: Can you Point the mouse cursor to the println() of System.out.println();, then press `F4` ?

Comment: do you have Sourcepath set up in the "Platform Settings | SDKs"? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56053801/18430882